# How do I use precompiled C libraries on a non-rooted device through Android Studio?

Tags: android, precompiled, android-native-library

I cross compiled a C library for Android. I copied the bin folder files to the Android xbin directory on a rooted device and I was able to use the library's commands. Can I do the same on a **non** rooted device through Android app/Android studio? I copied the files to the data/local/tmp directory but it did not work.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you want to do? Usually you do this with the NDK and JNI

Comment: I did not use NDK because I wanted to use a Uclibc toolchain. I have used the toolchain to cross compile the library then tried it on a rooted device.